# Using lm(), nls() (and glm()?) to estimate population growth rate in Malthusian growth model

Tags: r, regression, glm, lm, nls

My question is related to estimating the population growth rate in [Malthusian growth model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusian_growth_model). As a toy example, consider a toy dataset `df`:

```
structure(list(x= c(0L, 24L, 48L, 72L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L
), y = c(10000, 18744.0760659189, 35134.0387564953, 65855.509495469, 
123440.067934292, 231377.002294256, 433694.813090781, 812920.856596808
)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to fit this dataset by **exponential model**:

```
y = 10000 * (e^(r * x))
```

and estimate `r`. When using **nonlinear** regression `nls()`:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ (10000 * exp(r*x)), data=df)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall = as.list(match.call(func,  : 
  no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects
```

I also tried `lm()`

```
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ (10000 * exp(r*x)), data=df)
```

but get

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

How can I solve this? How can I fit the data to the exponential model I have?

Also, are there other approaches I could consider for fitting population growth model? Is `glm()` reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using lm()**

Please read `?formula` for correct specification of a formula. Now I will proceed assuming you have read that.

First, your model, after taking `log` transform on both LHS and RHS, becomes:

```
log(y) = log(10000) + r * x
```

The constant is a known value, not to be estimated. Such constant is called `offset` in `lm`.

You should use `lm` as this:

```
# "-1" in the formula will drop intercept
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ x - 1, data = df, offset = rep(log(10000), nrow(df)))

# Call:
#  lm(formula = log(y) ~ x - 1, data = df, offset = rep(log(10000), nrow(df)))

#  Coefficients:
#        x  
#  0.02618
```

As you've spotted, `fit` is a list of length 13. See the "Value" section of `?lm` and you will get better idea of what they are. Among those, the fitted values are `$fitted`, so you can draw your plot by:

```
plot(df)
lines(df$x, exp(fit$fitted), col = 2, lwd = 2)  ## red line
```

[image: fit]

Pay attention to my using `exp(fit$fitted)`, because we fit a model for `log(y)` and now we are going back to original scale.

**Remark**

As @BenBolker said, a simpler specification is:

```
fit <- lm(log(y/10000) ~ x - 1, data = df)
```

or

```
fit <- lm(log(y) - log(10000) ~ x - 1, data = df)
```

But the response variable is not `log(y)` but `log(y/10000)` now, so when you make plot, you need:

```
lines(df$x, 10000 * exp(fit$fitted), col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

---

**Using `nls()`**

Correct way for using `nls()` is as this:

```
nls(y ~ 10000 * exp(r * x), data = df, start = list(r = 0.1))
```

Because non-linear curve fitting requires iterations, a starting value is needed, and **must** be provided via argument `start`.

Now, if you try this code, you will get:

```
Error in nls(y ~ 10000 * exp(r * x), data = df, start = list(r = 0.1)) : 
  number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
```

The problem is because your data are exact, without noise. Have a read on `?nls`:

```
Warning:

     *Do not use ‘nls’ on artificial "zero-residual" data.*
```

So, using `nls()` for your toy data set `df` does not work.

Let's go back to check the fitted model from `lm()`:

```
fit$residuals
#            1             2             3             4             5 
#-2.793991e-16 -1.145239e-16 -2.005405e-15 -5.498411e-16  3.094618e-15 
#            6             7             8 
# 1.410007e-15 -1.099682e-15 -1.007937e-15
```

Residuals are basically 0 everywhere, and `lm()` does an exact fit in this case.

---

**Follow-up**

> One last thing that I haven't been able to figure out is why the parameter `r` is not used in `lm`'s formula specification.

There are actually some difference in the formula between `lm` and `nls`. Perhaps you can take it as such:

- `lm()`'s formula is called model formula, which you can read from `?formula`. It is so fundamental in R. Model fitting routines use it, like `lm`, `glm`, while many functions have formula method, like `model.matrix`, `aggregate`, `boxplot`, etc.
- `nls()`'s formula is more like a function specification, and really not widely used. Many other functions doing non-linear iterations like `optim` will not accept a formula but takes a function directly. So, just treat `nls()` as a special case.

> So would it make sense to do it using the linear model? Simply what I am trying to model here is using Malthusian growth model.

Strictly speaking, giving real population data (certainly with noise), using `nls()` for curve fitting, or using `glm(, family = poisson)` for a Poisson response GLM has better ground than fitting a linear model. The `glm()` call to your data would be:

```
glm(y ~ x - 1, family = poisson(), data = df, offset = rep(log(10000), nrow(df)))
```

(You possibly need to learn what a GLM is first.) But since your data have no noise, you will get warning message when using it.

However, in terms of computational complexity, using a linear model by first taking `log` transform is a clear win. In statistical modelling, variable transform are **very common**, so there is no compelling reason to reject the use of linear model for estimation of population growth rate.

As a complete picture, I recommend you try all three approaches for real data (or noisy toy data). There will be some difference in estimation and prediction, but unlikely to be very great.

**"Follow-follow-up"**

Haha, thanks to @Ben again. For `glm()`, we can also try:

```
glm(y ~ x - 1 + offset(log(10000)), family = gaussian(link="log"))
```

For `offset` specification, we can either use `offset` argument in `lm`/`glm`, or the `offset()` function as Ben does.

Comment: for linear models you don't even really need the offset: `log(y)-log(10000) ~ x -1` should work (although the offset might be clearer)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I cannot however input `log(y) = log(10000) + r * x` as it shows `could not find function "log<-"`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I actually got a bit confused, but now reading about the intercept, I understand it more clearly, one thing that is still problematic is that why lm results in list of 13. But then in this case I cannot use the fit from lm to draw a plot! I am using `plot(df)` and then `lines(x,fit)`. `fit` is basically `lm(log(y) ~ x - 1, data = df, offset = rep(log(10000), nrow(df)))`

Comment: Fantastic reply. Thank you! It now cleared up everything for me. One last thing that I haven't been able to figure out is why the parameter `r` is not used in `lm`, I am questioning this specifically because in what I am doing `r` is the growth rate of my model in a Bioinformatics task so it's quite important.

Comment: in a linear model specification, the coefficients are implicit rather than explicit.  See `coef(fit)`.  It might be a good idea to do some background reading on linear models if this is important to you ...

Comment: So would it make sense to do it using the linear model? Simply what I am trying to model here is using Malthusian growth model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusian_growth_model

Comment: `glm(y~x-1 + offset(log(10000)), family=gaussian(link="log"))` is another possibility

Comment: Is there any way to actually implement that "r" parameter and estimate it and then report on the "r" value that gave the best fit with the data points? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please, could you please explain when to use nls and when glm? Let say I want to fit a logistic model.